Плывет (зернится) текст в vs code
При установке на linux все шрифты программы стали пиксельными и нечеткими. При этом на win10 все работает как положено. ОС - alt k regular. Radeon RX 580.


Для сравнения как это выглядит на винде(слева) и на линуксе(справа)

Не вижу чтобы что-то плыло и зернилось. Единственно, что на втором скриншоте слева шрифт с более толстыми линиями.
